# Docker compose doesn't work correctly with yaml config

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Recently I've added the following command in command section of the docker-compose config file:

```
  livy:
    image: ecp/spark:${TAG:-latest}
    container_name: spark-livy
    ports:
      - "${LIVY_PORT:-8998}:8998"
    command: ["sh", "-c", "/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy-env.sh && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy.conf && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/log4j.properties &&  sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml"]
    volumes:
      - ./conf/livy-env.sh:/opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy-env.sh
      - ./conf/livy.conf:/opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy.conf
      - ./conf/log4j.properties:/opt/bitnami/livy/conf/log4j.properties
      - ./conf/hbase-site.xml:/opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml
      - ../../spark:/opt/bitnami/spark/app # pySpark scripts
    networks:
      - default_network
    depends_on:
      - spark
```

After that, when I try to rebuild or remove container with commands like "docker-compose build" or "docker-compose down && docker-compose rm" it just prints:

```
pavel@HP-ProBook:~/dp/docker/spark$ docker-compose down
$//' /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml" &&  sed -i 's/ service "livy": "/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server && sed -i 's/
pavel@HP-ProBook:~/dp/docker/spark$ docker-compose rm
$//' /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml" &&  sed -i 's/ service "livy": "/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server && sed -i 's/
```

and does nothing.

If I remove this part:

```
&& sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy-env.sh && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy.conf && sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/log4j.properties &&  sed -i 's/\r$//' /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml
```

and leave only

```
command: ["sh", "-c", "/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server"]
```

the script works normally.

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1):

When you stop the container, `livy-server` function exits. If it stops without error (exit code 0),only then does the remainder of `&&` commands get executed...

The better way to do this is to create your own Dockerfile

```
ARG TAG
FROM ecp/spark:${TAG}

WORKDIR /opt/bitnami/

COPY conf/livy.conf livy/conf/livy.conf
RUN ["sed",...]
# repeat for each 

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server"]
```

And

```
livy:
  build: 
    context: . 
    args:
     - TAG=${TAG:-latest}
```

However, none of your files should end with carriage returns anyway, so you really shouldn't be doing that specific sed command from compose or a Dockerfile. Use a text editor on your host, before mounting each file, to save the files with proper line endings

Answer (score 0):

**It's `\r` You should change it to `\\r`.**

Try to change the command to this:

```yaml
    command: ["sh", "-c", "/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server && sed -i 's/\\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy-env.sh && sed -i 's/\\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/livy.conf && sed -i 's/\\r$//' /opt/bitnami/livy/conf/log4j.properties &&  sed -i 's/\\r$//' /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/hbase-site.xml"]
```

How ever I don't think other commands execute! because if `/opt/bitnami/livy/bin/livy-server` be execute never exits to let other command run.

you should run them first or use a entrypoint script.